# Required is not working for image using yup validate

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am trying to validate using yup. Required is not working for image.

```
image: yup.string().required("required"),
```

I am using `formik` for required field. This is working for every field in form, but with image it's not working.
I have initialized the initial values:

```js
const initialValues = {
   image: "",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This yup validation for file upload

```
attachment: Yup.mixed()
.test(
  'FILE_SIZE',
  'File is required',
  value => value && value.size >= 10,
)
```

Comment: I just need required field. If image is not uploaded, should get required message.

Comment: yes remove the FILE_FORMAT test and just add 10 to {FILE_SIZE} so it will be required  field. and also change the validation message.

Comment: image: yup.mixed()
  .test(
  '10',
  'Uploaded file is too big.',
  value => value && value.size <= 10,
), I am using like this but still its not working.

Comment: Please use this: `.test(
  'FILE_SIZE', // it is not a variable it is an identifier  
  'Field is required.',
  value => value && value.size >= 10,
)`

Comment: No, its not working.

Comment: @nova_master solution worked for me, but can you explain why is it so and why required() won't work?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahNabeel no idea.